# Ожидание ответа от второго Observable в RxJava2

Tags: java, android, rxjava

У меня есть данные в локальной базе и данные с сервера. Я должен вывести сперва данные с локальной базы, если есть, иначе подождать данных от сервера. То есть, когда жду данных от сервера, я не должен скрывать `ProgressBar` до тех пор, пока не получу данных или пустой список и только потом скрывать `ProgressBar` и показать `Empty State`(сообщение о пустом списке).

Проблема в том, когда я получаю пустой список из локальной базы, `ProgressBar` скрывается и появляется `Empty State`, а потом подгружаются данные с сервера.

Код, где эта реализация:

```
    Observable.mergeDelayError(getDataFromLocal(), getDataFromServer())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
        .subscribe(transactions -> {
            if (mView != null) {

                mView.hideConnectingProgress();
                mView.onTransactionsReceived(transactions);

            } 
        }, throwable -> {
            if (mView != null) {
                mView.hideConnectingProgress();

                if (throwable instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                    mView.showOfflineMessage();
                } 
            }
        }
    )
```

Попробовал добавить Флаг типа `isLocalData = true` в `flatMap()` `getDataFromLocal()`, а в `flatMap()` `getDataFromServer() isLocalData = false`.

В подписчике так:

```
if (transactions.size() > 0) {
      mView.hideConnectingProgress();
      mView.onTransactionsReceived(transactions);
} else {
      if (!isLocalData) {
           mView.hideConnectingProgress();
           mView.onTransactionsReceived(transactions);
      }
}
```

Но в этом решении `Empty State` не появляется при получении пустого списка из локальной базы, когда интернета нет.

Вопрос:
Как реализовать получение `getDataFromLocal()`, если тут пусто, то не скрывая ProgressBar ждать getDataFromServer(), но если нет интернета, показать `Empty State` `getDataFromLocal()`.

Понимаю все запутанно, и я что-то не понимаю. Бьюсь с эти 2 дня. Можете подсказать, как реализовать?

Comment: Может как-то так? `getDataFromLocal().flatMap(data -> if(data.isEmpty) {return getDataFromServer();} else {return Observable.just(data);})`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,  Только в этом случае `getDataFromServer()` повторится два раза. То есть, пойдет запрос на сервер, если `getDataFromLocal()` вернет пустой список, потом если `getDataFromServer()` будет пустой, то еще раз повторится запрос. Так как, идет до `flatMap()` два запроса параллельно: `Observable.mergeDelayError(getDataFromLocal(), getDataFromServer())`

Comment: У меня в предложении нет `Observable.mergeDelayError(getDataFromLocal(), getDataFromServer())`. Просто сразу запрос в БД, а потом запрос в сеть, если надо. Так только один раз запрос в сеть отправится, если в БД пусто.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Просто данные в лок базе могут устареть, поэтому всегда параллельно подтягиваю данные с сервера. Если делать, как вы предложили, то новые данные не будут загружаться с сервера, если в локальной базе есть запись

Comment: Ну... Разве тогда не следует просто подряд запустить запросы в БД и в сеть?  Типа так: `getLocalData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread()).doOnSuccess(data -> if(data.isEmpty()){/*EMPTY STATE SHOW*/} else {/*DATA SHOW*/}).observeOn(Schedullers.io()).flatMap(data -> getServerData()).observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread()).subscribe(data -> {/*DATA SHOW*/}, error -> {/*ERROR SHOW*/})`

Comment: Думаю проще было бы использовать Maybe.zip(), во-первых результат нужен один, во вторых он (zip) параллельно вызовет оба метода getDataFromLocal() и getDataFromServer(), а затем из обоих результатов выбрать (по какой-то логике ) один и уже его вернуть.

Comment: Если вы уже нашли решение для своего вопроса - создайте, пожалуйста, ответ и пометьте его верным!